# Regex validate min and max hour in (H)H:mm format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JavaScript application and I am trying to get the following regex to work with `(H)H:mm` format for time from `00:01` or (`0:01`) and up to `22:00`:

`^(2[0-2]|[0-1]?[\d]):[0-5][\d]$`

The problem is that it also allows any minutes after 22, e.g. `22:59` is valid and I want to limit it to `22:00`.

Already searched for other posts, but couldn't find any with my criteria. Any suggestions are welcome because at this point I am not sure if I can do that with a pure regex, or if I should resort to JavaScript

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this?

Comment: @some can you think of a more efficient way to validate this type of input from the user? I think that a regex is the best in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a separate alternative for the `22:00` value and use

```
/^(?:(?:2[01]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d|22:00)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gVRimf/1).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of an outer non-capturing group used to make anchors apply to all the alternatives in the group

  - `(?:2[01]|[01]?\d):[0-5]\d`:

    - `(?:2[01]|[01]?\d)` - `20`, `21` or an optional `0` or `1` followed with any one digit, then
    - `:` - a colon
    - `[0-5]\d` - a digit from `0` to `5` and then any one digit
  - `|` - or
  - `22:00`  - a `22:00` string
- `)` - end of the outer group
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I didn't know that I can chain it like that. I'll accept the answer in 7 minutes.